# How to populate xml doc in div from another div like an iFrame using ajax?

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, xslt, mootools

I have a "sidebar" div with links that I would like to link up to some xml files. (with xslt that references three other xml files) I would like the xml to be displayed in the "body" div kinda like an iframe. I cannot find a good solution for this as I am using the browser's native XSL transformation and not "wrapping" the xml up into html. I have been looking into an ajax solution but can only find ajax scripts that populate html or txt files. I have also looked at jquerys .load() solution and mootools XMLRPC but is a little complicatingfor me. I am new with ajax and any help or direction would be greatly appreciated. Here is a link to my last post if you need more background info. [How to display XSLT in IE 8 and Chrome with javascript and three XML files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154507/how-to-display-xslt-in-ie-8-and-chrome-with-javascript-and-three-xml-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a SOLUTION. I used a server side php script I found on this site -
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128470/how-to-transform-xml-with-xslt-using-php-in-wordpress) 
Then I used this ajax script to load the xml -
[link](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/indexb.html)
It works perfectly. I am very happy. Now I would like to try and use a php scan script to scan the directory and another script to  create a new link to my new "populated" xml docs. CHALLENGING - yes we will see. Any info or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use the IE's default stylesheet**: DEFAULTSS.xsl

However, in the later versions of IE it cannot be readily downloaded as in the previous versions (res://msxml.dll/DEFAULTSS.xsl), so you need to find it by search.

**As this isn't standard XSLT**, I would recommend its adaptations such as the one contained in the **[XPath Visualizer](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html)**.

Comment: I used a server side php script I found on this site -
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128470/how-to-transform-xml-with-xslt-using-php-in-wordpress ) 
Then I used this ajax script to load the xml -
[link](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/indexb.html)
It works perfectly. I am very happy. Now I would like to try and use a php scan script to scan the directory and another script to  create a new link to my new "populated" xml docs. CHALLENGING - yes we will see. Any info or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: The solution I have described requires you only to apply an XSLT transformation on the XML file and to display the result in the browser. As for a list of XML files in a given directory, any programming language has its library for such functionality. From the description of the problem I don't think this is necessary to be done within the transformation, although this is possible with XSLT 2.0/ XPath 2.0, using the standard XPath 2.0 function `collection()`